# Why <a href="..." is not working?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. Trying to pass variable through href, but not working properly.Can someone please help TIA, here is my code:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>".$rows{'bi_SKU'}.
      "<td>".$rows{'bi_title'}.
      "<td>".$rows{'bi_author'}. 
      "</td>"
        "<td><a href=CopyAdd.php?SKU=".$rows{'bi_SKU'}.
```

Comment: You've got syntax errors. You don't concat the last 2 lines of the paste, and also, your HTML href ideally needs quotes.

Comment: Its syntax error. use `[ ]` (square braket) instead of `{ }` (curly bracket) in your array.

Comment: @NahidBinAzhar Use of braces is fine in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `href` value with quotes -

```
<a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=".$rows{'bi_SKU'}."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code...

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>".$rows{'bi_SKU'}.
      "<td>".$rows{'bi_title'}.
      "<td>".$rows{'bi_author'}. 
      "</td>"
        "<td><a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=".$rows{'bi_SKU'}."'
```

Note: Quotes is missing....

Answer (score 0):

Modify:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>".$rows{'bi_SKU'}.
  "<td>".$rows{'bi_title'}.
  "<td>".$rows{'bi_author'}. 
  "</td>".
    "<td><a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=".$rows{'bi_SKU'}."'>...</a>".
```

Comment: You should really add more explanation about the issue and how your answer fixes it.

Comment: When he analize properly this piece of code he will find the answer.

Comment: How are they going to learn if you just provide the code and not the reasoning. I suggest you keep it in mind when answering in the future, but up to you.

Comment: You are funny dude. No matter, I still think what I've wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

you missing quotes. Try it

```
<a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=".$rows{'bi_SKU'}."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "<tr>
           <td>".$rows{'bi_SKU'}."</td>
           <td>".$rows{'bi_title'}."</td>
           <td>".$rows{'bi_author'}."</td>
           <td><a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=".$rows{'bi_SKU'}."'>...</a></td>
        </tr>";
}
```

`td` & `tr` tags closed, `anchor` tag closed and quotes added to `href`.
When you indent the code properly most of the syntax errors can be spotted easily. Also use a good IDE to do that for you.

Comment: why you use `{ }` brackets with an array? It will `[ ]` brackets like `$rows['bi_SKU']`

Comment: I just copied the question & I learnt from this question that it doesn't matter. :)

Comment: Hey, Thanks very much eNeMetcH... problem solved. and thanks everyone for your response.

Comment: @NahidBinAzhar try this `$test = array('35', '56', '123', 'string');
echo $test{0};`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the single quote is not the problem.
The problem is that he missed the closing anchor tag.
**`href` should work without single quotes also**.
Solution is you need to close the anchor tag first .

```
"<td><a href=CopyAdd.php?SKU=".$rows{'bi_SKU'}.">...</a>".
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not closing your `<td>`.
2. Link is not closed: `<a></a>`
3. Missing link text: `<a>CLICK</a>`
4. Your `href` is missing `'` around value: `<a href='#'>CLICK</a>`
5. Array elements are accessed via `[]` but not via `{}` (turn on error reporting to see errors).
6. You are using **mysql_** that is deprecated. Use **PDO** or **mysqli_**

You can use `"` and surround variable with `{}` to put it safely in string.

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
         <td>{$rows['bi_SKU']</td>
         <td>{$rows['bi_title']}</td>
         <td>{$rows['bi_author']}</td>
         <td>
             <a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU={$rows{'bi_SKU'}'>SKU</a>
         </td>
   </tr>";
}
```